# Outlook: unable to search in subfolders of shared mailboxes

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2016, shared-mailbox

A few days ago, we took our last users off Outlook 2013 client and placed them on Outlook 2016.

After this, they were no longer able to search in the subfolders of multiple shared mailboxes.

Is there a way to search to more than one mailbox their subfolders? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> doesn't allow more than one data file.

If needed, I can use automapping or map them myself. Most important is that the search option is working properly again.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Try to turn off cached mode for shared folders in *File > Account Settings > double-click account name > More Settings > Advanced tab*, clear the check mark from download shared folders. If that's not enough, see [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/581f1e61-a479-48e9-813a-5478cca8de99/searching-a-shared-mailbox-in-outlook-2016-behaviour-is-just-weird?forum=Office2016ITPro) for more settings that may be required.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is by design that we can only search current folder for shared folders. To include the shared mailbox in the scope, you need to manually reselect Current Folder.

Please check this blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Global-Customer-Service/Understanding-Search-Scopes-in-Microsoft-Outlook/ba-p/428841

This was also mentioned in this TechNet thread: [Search subfolders of shared folders](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e0ed3a8f-8791-40dd-8c26-e62b5639466b/search-subfolders-of-shared-folders?forum=outlook)